# Implementation of getdelim

Tags: beginner, c, file, io

**Note:** I wasn't trying to follow the POSIX `getdelim` signature exactly. I needed to add the `consume` argument for a project I'm working on.

I am pretty new to writing C. It would be great to get some feedback on whether best practices are being followed.

Some things I learned about while writing this code (which might be areas that need improvement)

- Pointer arithmetic
- `FILE *` error handling

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

ssize_t read_until_deliminator(char **buffer, size_t *size, char deliminator, 
                               FILE *file, bool consume)
{
        char ch;
        char *buffer_pos;

        if (buffer == NULL || size == NULL || ferror(file)) {
                errno = EINVAL;
                return -1;
        }

        if (buffer == NULL || *size == 0) {
                // Empty buffer supplied
                *size = 128;
                *buffer = malloc(*size);

                if (*buffer == NULL) {
                        errno = ENOMEM;
                        return -1;
                }
        }

        buffer_pos = *buffer;

        for (;;) {
                ch = getc(file);

                if (ch == EOF) {
                        break;
                }

                if ((buffer_pos + 1) == (*buffer + *size)) {
                        // No more room in buffer
                        size_t new_size = *size * 2;
                        char* realloc_buffer = realloc(*buffer, new_size);

                        if (realloc_buffer == NULL) {
                                errno = ENOMEM;
                                return -1;
                        }

                        buffer_pos = realloc_buffer + (buffer_pos - *buffer);
                        *buffer = realloc_buffer;
                        *size = new_size;
                }

                *buffer_pos++ = ch;

                if (ch == deliminator) {
                        if (!consume) {
                                // If not consuming delim roll back buffer
                                buffer_pos--;
                        }

                        break;
                }
        }

        if (ch == EOF && buffer_pos == *buffer) {
                return -1;
        }

        *buffer_pos = '\0';

        return buffer_pos - *buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
        size_t buffer_size = 50;
        char *buffer = malloc(buffer_size);

        ssize_t result = read_until_deliminator(&buffer, &buffer_size, 'c', stdin, false);

        printf("Result: %zd\n", result);
        printf("Buffer Size: %zu\n", buffer_size);
        printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);

        free(buffer);
}
```

**Minimal working example:** https://repl.it/repls/SlimEarlyField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good job!

A few notes:

1. It is better to check for a **malloc** error right away instead of going to another function to check. Just like what you did with **realloc**.
2. Your function **read_until_deliminator**
   returns an error but your implementation never checks for this error return
   value.
3. I will do separation of concern, where you will obtain the input and find the delimiter in different functions. This is just to aid in code maintenance so it helps with readability for you and others.

I will post my changes later in the day.

Answer (score 2):

If we pass a null buffer, expecting it to be allocated for us, then we'll be surprised, because the first check will return a failure here:

> ```
>     if (buffer == NULL || size == NULL || ferror(file)) {
>             errno = EINVAL;
>             return -1;
>     }
>
>     if (buffer == NULL || *size == 0) {
> ```

Perhaps those conditional blocks need to be in the opposite order?  And the buffer/size check to be `&&` rather than `||`?

Kudos for using `realloc()` correctly (testing the result before assigning to `*buffer` - you've avoided a common mistake there.

Minor (spelling) - "delimiter", not "deliminator".